# Start PHP script when <docker compose up -d> that runs permanently

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to start a PHP script when the docker containers are started with `docker compose up -d`?

E.g. if there are two containers: The PHP-Container and a MariaDB-Container.
The PHP-Script should collect data from an API and save them into the MariaDB-Container when the docker containers are started.

I tried `CMD [php script.php]` in the Dockerfile and tried to modify the ENTRYPOINT of the Dockerfile:

```
COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container
ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

I also tried [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) following [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) guide, put the "wait-for-it.sh" in the same folder as the Dockerfile and added following lines to the dockerfile:

```
COPY wait-for-it.sh wait-for-it.sh 
RUN chmod +x wait-for-it.sh
CMD ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mariadb:3306" , "--strict" , "--timeout=60", "start_data_collection.sh"]
```

I also wrote a bash-script that starts the php script because I was not sure whether the php script can be executed from a dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wait for mysql in your bash script :

```
while !(mysqladmin ping > /dev/null 2>&1)
do
   sleep 3
done
```

and then call your php script.

You can use --host/--port option on mysqladmin to point to your other container. Be aware that you might need to handle the authentication to the mysql server.

---

If you don't want to do that, and keep the simple tcp check, you should add a `--` like so, if we follow the examples from the github you linked :

```
CMD ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mariadb:3306" , "--strict" , "--timeout=60", "--", "start_data_collection.sh"]
```

Because you want to run start_data_collection.sh at the end of wait-for-it.sh, you don't want to pass it as argument to the wait-for-it.sh script

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to implement your answer but I wasn't able to do that. I tried to put:
while !(mysqladmin ping > /dev/null 2>&1) {
    sleep(3);
}
into the php but it doesnt work

Comment: You need to adapt the command to your needs, by providing host/port options and so on. And also note that this is bash, not php

Comment: I tried everything but I can't get it to work. Is it even really sure that the script does not work because of this? The PHP script only writes data to the MariaDB database in the Docker container. What also surprises me is that the PHP container is not started until the MariaDB container is started, because in the docker-compose.yml of the PHP container there is a "depends-on: mariadb", which actually means that the container can only be started when the MariaDB container is started.

Comment: Well it should work, try to put a echo in start_data_collection.sh to see if it's actually called